# If $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1 ;$ prove that $\sqrt[3]{a x^{2}+b y^{2}+c z^{2}}=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c} .$

Tags: polynomials

If $a x^{3}=b y^{3}=c z^{3}$ and $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1 ;$ prove that $\sqrt[3]{a x^{2}+b y^{2}+c z^{2}}=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c} .$

Thanks!

Comment: What's the source of these questions?

Comment: I am preparing for an olympiad so there is a book named "Pathfinder" Most of the questions that i ask are from that book .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $ax^3 = by^3 = cz^3 = k $.

Show that $k = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$ and that $\sqrt[3]{k} = \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} + \sqrt[3]{c}$, hence the result follows.

---

> $k = \frac{k}{x} + \frac{k}{y} + \frac{k}{z} = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$

> $\sqrt[3]{k} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{k}}{ x} + \frac{\sqrt[3]{k}}{ y} + \frac{\sqrt[3]{k}}{ z}  = \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} + \sqrt[3]{c}$